# Is there a way to expedite the process of the "pending review" of my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have uploaded my chrome extension and it's currently "pending review" for a long time.
It is absolutely simple, one feature add-on, so there shouldn't be any questions or difficulties.
Is there any way to contact Google Support in order to understand what is the problem with the extension?

Answer (score 1):

How long is "long time" to you? Per their policy they can take up to 7 days. I had mine stuck in "pending review" for over a month last summer. I contacted them about the issue at `cws-developer-support@google.com` and it was promptly accepted after that. This is what I recommend doing.